# String Manipulation in Batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I'm running a FOR loop to retrieve the (absolute) path name for ALL *.properties file in the root folder: "C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\". Now, I'm trying to slice the path name to only result in the file name. e.g. if absolute path is "C\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Test-101" I only want the "Test-101" part (w/out the quotes of course) I have:

```
    FOR %%G IN (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO
    (
         REM Ignore "C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\" ??
         java -jar %1 %G:> Logs\%%G.log
    )
```

So the absolute file path name is stored in G, but I'd only like the file name. How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
%%~nG
```

to get just the filename, or

```
%%~nxG
```

if you want the filename and extension.